# How to Get Data from Stored Procedure in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I read data from my stored procedure. When I insert a breakpoint I get this situation:

[image]

The stored procedure returns one row with 8 columns. You can see this on a picture. But when I am trying to read one value:

```
var post_id = reader[4].ToString();
```

I got this exception:

> Invalid attempt to read when no data is present.

My model:

```
  public class Alarm
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public int Snoozes { get; set; }
    public bool Repeat { get; set; }
    public DateTime AlarmUpdateTime { get; set; }

    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    public virtual List<FacebookNotificationStatus> StatusUpdates { get; set; }
}

public class FacebookStatusUpdate
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime FacebookUpdateTime { get; set; }
    public string PostId { get; set; }
    public DateTime? FacebookPostTime { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset ClientTime { get; set; }
    public int Offset { get; set; }

    public virtual FacebookNotificationStatus Status { get; set; }
    public virtual Alarm Alarm { get; set; }
}
```

Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

after executing command.ExecuteReader() you can loop through data with next code (just sample):

```
var rdr = command.ExecuteReader();
while(rdr.Read()) 
{
  var obj = new MyClass();
  obj.Id = (int)rdr["Id"];
  if (rdr["Name"] != DBNull.Value)
  {
    obj.name = (string)rdr["Name"];
  }
}
rdr.Close();
```

this sample reads all fetched data from DB row-by-row.

Also don't forget to read read [SqlDataReader manual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for more information how to work with readers.

Answer (score 2):

You need to call the `reader.Read()` before reading the records.

**Example:**

```
 String column1="";
 String column2="";
 while(reader.Read())
    {
      column1 = reader["column1"].ToString();
      column2 = reader["column2"].ToString();
    }
```

Comment: And you need to loop while `reader.Read() == true` to get all the records.

Answer (score 1):

Dealing with all the subtleties of ADO.NET is not fun; frankly, I suspect you might find it easier to use something like "dapper", which allows:

```
using(var conn = ...)
{
    return conn.Query<FacebookStatusUpdate>("GetPostList"),
       commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure).ToList();
}
```

(assuming that the column names are a direct match to the property names on `FacebookStatusUpdate`)

And for passing parameters:

```
string region = ...
DateTime minDate = ...
using(var conn = ...)
{
    return conn.Query<FacebookStatusUpdate>("GetPostList"),
       new { region, minDate },
       commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure).ToList();
}
```

Comment: It works but didn't save relationship.  I have one table Alarm and FacebookStatusUpdate. So FBSU include Alarm id. When I use query in field Alarm I got null

Comment: I add my model in the description.

Comment: @Oleh indeed; your use of `virtual` suggests you might be using EF under the hood; however, mapping to a complex hierarchy is complex if the data isn't all readily available in the query

Comment: Thanks a lot. I remember this example. In the future I will use this method.